# How to set state of react-select component state when isMulti={true}?

Tags: typescript, onchange, setstate, react-select

Here is part of my code:

Table which I use:

```
const options = [
  { value: 'Orange', label: 'Orange' },
  { value: 'Banana', label: 'Banana' },
  { value: 'Apple', label: 'Apple' },
];
```

I create state "value" which is a table with initial state of empty table:
 value: [].

```
 private handleChange(value: any) {
    this.setState({ value: value });
  }

<Select
          value={this.props.selection}
          onChange={() => this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          options={options}
          isClearable={true}
          isMulti={true}
        />
```

{this.props.selection} is a type of the following class:

```
export class Selection {
  value: string;
  label: string;

  constructor(
    value: string,
    label: string,
  ) {
    this.value = value;
    this.label = label;
  }
}
```

When I select options from Select component the "value" state doesn't change.
Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback you are assigning to 
`onChange={() => this.handleChange.bind(this)}` is actually not doing anything each time you change a value in your Select. The only thing that it does is to bind `this` to handleChange. It will not call the function.

It's enough to pass the result of binding which is already a function.

`onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}`

Think about this

```
function sum(a,b){
   return a+b;
}

const sumWithNoArgs = () => sum.bind(null, 1,2);
```

If we now call sumWithNoArgs() we will get a new function instead of the sum. This is exactly what select does, it calls the function you are passing.

You have to do

```
const sumWithNoArgs = () => sum.bind(null, 1,2)();
```

so we we call SumWithNoArgs() we get the propper result.

You need to either make the binding of your function in the constructor or declare the function as a class variable so it's automatically bound to your class.